# PHP Input & file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Can someone explain me why when i POST RAW Data for example "test.txt" in the below script

```
<?php

echo file_get_contents("php://input");

?>
```

it only prints the text "test.txt" instead of the file contents of that file?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want the content of a local file, of the content from a client file?

Comment: It isn't a file, it's a stream containing your raw POST data. What's the problem? It did what you asked it to? Are you trying ***the highly insecure*** `echo file_get_contents(file_get_contents("php://input"));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code reads the contents of the raw POST data and echoes it back.

Whereas what you want is this:

```
// retrieve the requested filename
$fileName = file_get_contents("php://input");

// echo the contents of the requested file
echo file_get_contents($fileName);
```

Depending on what you're trying to, you may wish to sanitize the `$fileName` input (not shown: too broad) and restrict access to a specific local directory:

```
$path = $myLocalDirectory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
if (file_exists($path) {
    echo file_get_conents($path);
}
```

Comment: Note that this has major security issues, because everybody could read data from any file

Comment: @SanderVisser duly amended. It answers the question: anything further is dependent on what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes i know that it has security issue. No worries :). Thanks for your answer

Comment: @bcmcfc A bit late, but please note that your sanitation doesn't limit you to that directory (`../../index.php`). `ltrim($fileName, './')` would work wonders, but wouldn't work with hidden files (`.htaccess`).

Comment: @h2ooooooo well, yeah - there is no sanitation of the fileName, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @bcmcfc Ah okay, it was just confusing seeing as you mentioned "you may want to do something" followed by a colon usually meaning "here's an example of what you may want to do".

Answer (score 0):

Try like this ..

```
$input = "abc.txt";
echo file_get_contents($input);
```

It gives the content of the text file `abc.txt`